# Use the result of a sub-query outside of the sub-query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table structured like this.

| User_id | Subscription_type | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | PAYING | 2/10/2021 |
| 99 | TRIAL | 2/10/2021 |
| 100 | TRIAL | 15/9/2021 |

I want my output to be the same, with an additional column pulling the trial start date when the subscriber converts to a paying subscription.

| User_id | Subscription_type | timestamp | Trial_Start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | PAYING | 2/10/2021 | 15/9/2021 |
| 99 | TRIAL | 2/10/2021 |  |
| 100 | TRIAL | 2/10/2021 |  |

At the moment, I have this query:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN    
            (SELECT `subscription_type` FROM subscription_event se1
            WHERE se1.`timestamp` < se.`timestamp` AND se1.user_id = se.user_id
            ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1) = 'TRIAL'
        then se1.`timestamp` else 0 end as "Converted_from_TRIAL"

FROM subscription_event se
```

I have an error message with se1.`timestamp` not been defined. I understand why, but I cannot see a workaround.

Any pointer?

Comment: Why is the `timestamp` in the last row of the result `2/10/2021`? Shouldn't it be `15/9/2021` like in the input table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get two values out of the subquery, you have to join with it, not use it as an expression.

```
SELECT se.*,
    MAX(se1.timestamp) AS Converted_from_TRIAL
FROM subscription_event AS se
LEFT JOIN subscription_event AS se1 ON se.user_id = se1.user_id AND se1.timestamp < se.timestamp AND se1.subscription_type = 'TRIAL'
GROUP BY se.user_id, se.subscription_type, se.timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!
For some reasons I needed to declare explicitely in SELECT the variables used in the GROUP BY . Not sure why ( I am using MySQL5.7 so maybe it is linked with that).
In any case, this is the working query.

```
SELECT se.user_id, se.subscription_type, se.timestamp,
    MAX(se1.timestamp) AS Converted_from_TRIAL
    
FROM subscription_event AS se

LEFT JOIN subscription_event AS se1 ON se.user_id = se1.user_id AND se1.timestamp < se.timestamp AND se1.subscription_type = 'TRIAL'

GROUP BY se.user_id, se.subscription_type, se.timestamp
```